# How can I edit values in memory?

Tags: ram

Is it possible to edit values in memory used by an app?  I would assume this requires root.

Comment: what do you need to do this for? I would assume that trying to do this would be very difficult due to android's sandboxing structure.

Comment: Which type of values you are talking about?

Comment: @SachinShekhar like counters? for example a button press counter or something.

Answer (score 4):

That may be possible without root if the app you want to manipulate allows debugging via Android Debug Bridge (ADB). If an app can be connected to an debugger is specified in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `android:debuggable` entry.

If the app is enabled for debugging you can enable the USB debugging mode on your device and connect to it via adb. Then you can connect an standard Java debugger to the app and inspect/modify variables.

If it does not allow debugging you can try to decompile it using `apktool`, change the debuggable value in `AndroidManifest.xml` and the re-build and sign the app (using a custom generated key pair).

A second alternative would be to include [Frida Gadget](https://frida.re/docs/gadget/) into the app and load it at run-time. Then you can use Frida to connect to the app on an unrooted device and hook Java or native methods as well as modify app memory.

Comment: Should try it with a dummy app to see!

Answer (score 2):

In Android the system memory is just another file, so with the appropriate rights it's just as simple as `vi -b /dev/mem` (device node may vary for your system). The result of changing a running system's memory could be one of a nop, a touch of an electric fence, a system crash or a simple nuke resulting in an unusable device.

Comment: how can you get an unusable device? I'd imagine the running apps would be in a different device from the actual ROM stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a program called `ACE Engine`
to scan and edit memory value of any running app or program in android
which can be download [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1053155227899003001/1054421925683789908/release.zip)

you need to install  the program
with adb and run the program in adb shell

1. run `ACE engine` and select a process which you want to edit its value.
2. scan for value in process's memory,
   like a coin, health or anything
3. you may got a couple of matches result
   you can reduces the matches, by changing
   the value in the game and scan for the new value
   to reduce scan results
4. repeat the processes until you got 1 match
5. write any value to the address to change
   the game/apk's value

you can find more details in the tutorial
[here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UlGm1nFxRzA&t=4s)

**DISCLAIMER!!!: I am the author of this program**